# How to include files in a directory in vite?

Tags: npm, webpack, vite

In webpack I use the following code to include all the .ts files as entry point.

> ```
> const path = require('path');
> const fs = require('fs');
>
> const generateEntryPoints = () => {
>     const entry = {};
>     const scriptDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts');
>     const files = fs.readdirSync(scriptDir).filter(file => file.endsWith('.ts'));
>
>     files.forEach(file => {
>         const name = path.basename(file, '.ts');
>         entry[name] = path.resolve(scriptDir, file);
>     });
>
>     return entry;
> };
> ```

But in vite I get the error:

> Error: Dynamic require of "path" is not supported

So, what is the equivalent code of the above in vite?